# Select the records which weren't selected from a SELECT

Tags: sqlite, select

I select all the records from a table `LABELS`, I and I use also `INNER JOIN` to get with my `SELECT` some other data which exist in other tables. So my query is:

```
SELECT LABELS.oldLabel, LABELS.label, LABELS.version, LABELS.description, LABELS.type, LABELS.cutter, LABELS.valid, LABELS.dateCreated, LABELS.dateModified, CUSTOMERS.name AS customer, CUSTOMERS.id, SUPPLIERS.name AS supplier FROM LABELS 
INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS 
ON LABELS.customer = CUSTOMERS.id 
INNER JOIN SUPPLIERS 
ON LABELS.supplier = SUPPLIERS.id 
GROUP BY LABELS.oldLabel, LABELS.label, LABELS.version, LABELS.description, LABELS.type, LABELS.cutter, LABELS.customer, LABELS.valid, CUSTOMERS.name , CUSTOMERS.id, SUPPLIERS.name
```

The size of the records in the table `LABELS` is `3169`. However, the above statement returns `3089`. `80` records are missing.

Is there a way to get all the records, except from the above select in order to see which are these records and figure out why they are not selected ?

I tried:

```
Select * FROM labels where not exists( the_above_select)
```

But I don't get any records..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * from Labels WHERE label NOT IN 
(SELECT  label from Labels INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS
   ON LABELS.customer = CUSTOMERS.id 
   INNER JOIN SUPPLIERS 
   ON LABELS.supplier = SUPPLIERS.id)
```